# Difference between definitions of spline-based regressions

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, splines, mars

Good day, XValidators.

Going over the definitions of spline-based regressions, like MARS, I've found 2 that appear the same, but are not. They are not rigorous, but at my level of expertise, rigorous notation only clouds meaning.

> Assuming a 2-var dataset that doesn't exhibit a linear relationship, we could fit a linear model to only a portion of the data, then another, then another, until we have a piecewise monomial describing all the data.

And the second is:

> Assume a 2-var dataset that shows a non-linear relationship. We could fit several non-linear curves to subsequent parts of the data, so that our overall model is a linear combination of these non-linear curves.

So, for example, in what definition would MARS fall in? Are both correct? Is the 1st related to lineal splines and the second to quadratic or cubic splines? Are both, ultimately, the same?

Thanks, everyone.

J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MARS can be viewed as multiple piece wise linear regressions. Each break point in MARS defines a separate region of linear relationship. Therefore, your second model definition does not fall under MARS.

[MARS- Check slide 3](http://www.ideal.ece.utexas.edu/courses/ee380l_ese/2013/mars.pdf)

There is something called a Generalized Additive Model (GAM), which allows you to have separate smoothing functions in different regions. This is more like your second model definition.

[GEM Link-Page 7 image at bottom left](http://www3.nd.edu/~mclark19/learn/GAMS.pdf)